# Removing Dependency From Controller Constructor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am creating a MVC application using NINject as my IOC. I am trying to separate my business logic from controller. And so I don't want my controller constructor creates for my any Dependency Object i.e. I dont want to pass my interface in the constructor and than it gets resolved through IOC container. It should be the responsibility of the business logic layer. I am trying to achieve something like below.

```
public BusinessHolidayController()
{

}
// GET: BusinessHoliday
public ActionResult Index(Product product)
{
    string model = invoke<IProduct>().GetSum(product);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: its a generic method

Comment: Well that can be the busienss logic class or may be I can write a extension method for the controller to resolve dependencies and than get the required object.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? What do you mean by "Dependency Object"? Most importantly, what's the question?

Comment: Are you saying you want something like a "Component Factory" that resolves all dependencies and that that "Component Factory" must reside in the "business logic"?

Comment: Kind of. with the above syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are above to do is leaning toward **Service Locator Pattern** which is anti-pattern and a dangerous pattern. Its disadvantages are greater than its advantages.

There are four basic DI patterns -

1. Constructor Injection
2. Property Injection
3. Method Injecton
4. Ambient Context

For MVC controller, you want to use Constructor Injection, because it is the best pattern of the above four patterns especially for controller.

> It should be the responsibility of the business logic layer.

No. Composite Root should be placed entry point of the application such as Global.asax.

For more information, you want to read [Mark Seemann's Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501).

Comment: do you mean I should resolve my dependency in Global.asax or the IOC container initializer.